# Check value fields that if the same empty value in last field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several field that just get number, I want if user typed be identical value in two or more field empty value the last field that is identical by jQuery.keyup?

For Example:

```
<input name="num[]" value="11111">
<input name="num[]" value="33333">
<input name="num[]" value="11111"> // in this input should empty value it.
```

How can fix it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $("input").blur(function(){
   var _val = $(this).val();
   var change = false;
   $("input").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == _val){
          if(change) $(this).val("");
          else change = true;
      }

   })

  })
})
```

Comment: use .blur for instead of onchange

Comment: I suggested `onchange` rather than `onblur` because if I'm tabbing through a bunch of input fields, but not changing them, it'd be more efficient to not bother checking all input fields for duplicates ;)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if I had `12345` in a box, then I went back to an earlier box and typed `123456`? The `12345` would be cleared. I suggest:

1. Bind the check to `onchange`, NOT `onkeyup`.
2. Instead of clearing the value, change the background colour to red and disable the submit button.
3. Adjust Yorgo's code to achieve this end, because it seems to do what you asked.

Comment: This is a true observation. Plus it's not very user friendly to just wipe out things the user entered without letting them know what the problem is